# Code Completion for Springs Groovy/Grails IDE

Tags: grails

Does Spring's Groovy/Grails Tool Suite 3.0.0 support code completion for the dynamically generated methods?

Comment: Yes it does. But you do have to install all the packages

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by packages. I've added all the extensions that look seem to be grails/groovy related.

Comment: I have recently updated eclipse 3.7 to STS 3.0. One strange issue I have seen is that if you STS 3.0 through eclipse's marketplace pane, and you install it, you may not see all the packages. But if you manually add http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/market-place/e3.7/ to Install new software, I could see some additional packages